# Select column with the most entries of a specific value in mySQL & Python

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

How would I find the column with the most entries of a specific value in a mySQL database with Python?

I have the following table:

```
| product |    id1    |    id2    |    id3    |
-----------------------------------------------
| apple   | 'ordered' |           | 'ordered' |
| banana  |           |           |           |
| bread   | 'ordered' | 'ordered' |           |
| milk    | 'ordered' |           | 'ordered' |
```

How can I find out which column (in this case, id1) has the most 'ordered' strings in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use count as follows:

```
Select case when greatest(id1,id2,id3) = id1 then 'id1' 
            When greatest(id1,id2,id3) = id2 then 'id2'
            else 'id3' end grt 
  From
(Select count(case when id1 = 'ordered' then 1 end) as id1,
       count(case when id2 = 'ordered' then 1 end) as id2,
       count(case when id3 = 'ordered' then 1 end) as id3
  From t) t
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pymysql` with a query that utilizes `union all` and a subquery to fetch the maximum results:

```
import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='user', password='passwd', database='db', charset='utf8mb4', cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
with connection:
   with connection.cursor() as cursor:
      cursor.execute("""
       with cte(col, r) as (
         select 'id1', sum(t1.id1 = 'ordered') from my_table t1
         union all
         select 'id2', sum(t1.id2 = 'ordered') from my_table t1
         union all
         select 'id2', sum(t1.id3 = 'ordered') from my_table t1
       )
       select c1.col from cte c1 where c1.r = (select max(c2.r) from cte c2);
       """
      )
      result = cursor.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is big `case` comparison:

```
select (case when sum(id1 = 'ordered') > sum(id2 = 'ordered') and
                  sum(id1 = 'ordered) > sum(id3 = 'ordered')
             then 'id1'
             when sum(id2 = 'ordered') > sum(id3 = 'ordered')
             then 'id2'
             else 'id3'
        end)
from t;
```

However, I think I prefer unpivoting and using window functions:

```
select which
from ((select 'id1' as which, count(*) as cnt where id1 = 'ordered'
      ) union all
      (select 'id2', count(*) as cnt where id2 = 'ordered'
      ) union all
      (select 'id3', count(*) as cnt where id3 = 'ordered'
      )
     ) i
order by cnt desc
limit 1;
```